# why is my drop-down menu not showing when hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, google-apps-script

I'm creating a menu using angularJS and google app script inside a dialog box.

I'm using [this example code](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/W6hwgE) as a reference.

so without having to copy and paste all of my code here is basically what I came up to:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.menu = [
    ["first", 
      ["item1", "item 2"]],
    ["second", 
      ["item 1", "item 2"]]
  ];
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

.firstLevel {
  display: inline-block;
}

li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <div ng-repeat="m in menu" class="firstLevel">
      <li>
        <a href="#">{{m[0]}}-</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <div ng-repeat="msub in m[1]">
            <a>{{msub}}</a>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would like the submenu to show and I suspect there's a problem with this piece of CSS
`li:hover > ul`.

So what I'm doing here is create a list that is parsing through an array for first item then creating another list that is parsing inside items or `array[1]`.
when I delete the `display: none`everything shows so the problem doesn't come from here.

At first I though it was a limitation of google app script HTML service but when I tried this code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1xy7o89/2/) I got the same problem.

Weird thing is that it works in the example and I've tried respecting the same element hierarchy.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @I'-'I didnt worked neither

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hovering over the first `<li>` which has no `<ul>` child. That is in the second `<li>`. I put the dropdown as a child into the first `<li>`, now it works.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.menu = [
    ["first", 
      ["item1", "item 2"]],
    ["second", 
      ["item 1", "item 2"]]
  ];
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

.firstLevel {
  display: inline-block;
}

li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <div ng-repeat="m in menu" class="firstLevel">
      <li>
        <a href="#">{{m[0]}}-</a>
         <ul>
          <div ng-repeat="msub in m[1]">
            <a>{{msub}}</a>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)